# Node SSH2 sudo password

Tags: node.js, ssh

I'm trying to use the node SSH2 package. This is my code

```js
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var password = 'xxxxxx'
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.exec('sudo ls -la', { pty: true }, function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;
        stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
            console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
            conn.end();
        }).on('data', function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf(':') >= data.length - 2) {
            stream.write(password + '\n');
            }
            else {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }
        }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
        });
    });
}).connect({
    host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    port: 22,
    username: 'user',
    password: 'xxxxx',
});

// example output:
// Client :: ready
// STDOUT:  17:41:15 up 22 days, 18:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
//
// Stream :: exit :: code: 0, signal: undefined
// Stream :: close
```

When I run the code it prompts for the password as follows:

```
Client :: ready
STDOUT: [sudo] password for venafi:
```

How can write the password into the password prompt?

Comment: OK so I moved the `stream.write(password + '\n');` into the `.on('data', function(data)` function and now sends the sudo password. However for some reason it write the sudo password out multiple times. e.g.

STDOUT: Passw0rd
STDOUT: Passw0rd
STDOUT: Passw0rd

Comment: OK so I worked it out and have updated my example to help anybody else that hits this problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I worked it out and have updated my example to help anybody else that hits this problem. This is the code I needed.

```js
if (data.indexOf(':') >= data.length - 2) {
            stream.write(password + '\n');
            }
            else {
                console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }
```